# MySQL querying table - Doesn't show first result

Tags: php, mysql

I have a DB (quartos) created with the following structure:

```
id_quarto  tipo_quarto  vista_quarto |
a      Single   Mar | 
b      Single   Mar |
c      Single   Mar | 
d      Single   Serra |
```

I want it to return the results of id_quarto, when tipo_quarto=Single and vista_quarto=Mar which values come from a form.

So i write the following:

```
$strSQL = "
SELECT id_quarto 
FROM quartos 
WHERE tipo_quarto='". $_POST['tipo_quarto'] ."' 
    AND vista_quarto='". $_POST['vista_quarto'] ."'";
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
```

Then i loop it and write in a table as followed:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
<?
<table border="1">
     <tr align="left">
         <td width="75"><?php echo $row['id_quarto']; ?></td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

The problem here is that it does not return the id_quarto=a , only b and c. Why is that and what can i do to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: dont use directly the POST variables in the sql query. this is sql injection imminent!

Comment: @ElzoValugi if I use mysql_real_escape_string() for POST would that do for the SQL injection problem (bare with me i'm a newbie)?

Comment: that is not enough, use filter_var functions.

Comment: @ElzoValugi is there any site newbie friendly to look for more information about the subject?

Comment: http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have extra `$row = mysql_fetch_array($rs);` just after `mysql_query($strSQL);`.  Then in `while` loop you read `$row` again (second row in resultset). 
So your code will look

```
$strSQL = "SELECT id_quarto FROM quartos 
  WHERE tipo_quarto='". $_POST['tipo_quarto'] ."' 
  AND vista_quarto='". $_POST['vista_quarto'] ."'";
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
// $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs); Don't need this line!!!
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) 
{
   // output ....
}
```

Also, it always makes sense to add code for handling mysql errors.

Comment: @user1139233 You can use the `mysql_data_seek` function to reset the row pointer by placing `mysql_data_seek($rs, 0);` right before you start the while loop but after `$row = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
`